# (JFrame) How do I read a random number to compare in a different method without displaying it?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm trying to make a number guessing game. When the user presses the start button, the program will randomly generate a number. The user can then input a number and the program will tell the user if they need to go higher or lower, after 8 guesses the program stops.

I have managed to generate a random number and write a loop that allows the user to guess 8 times. There are no compiling errors but I get a lot of errors when pressing the "guessBtn". This is my code:

```
private void startBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Random rand = new Random();
    int getal = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
}                                        

private void guessBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String randomNumTxt = startBtn.getText();
    int getal = Integer.parseInt(randomNumTxt);
    String gokNumTxt = guessTxt.getText();
    int gok = Integer.parseInt(gokNumTxt);
    int aantalGok = 0;

    while ((gok != getal) && (aantalGok <9)){
        if (gok < getal){
            antwoordLbl.setText("Hoger!");
            aantalGok++;
        }
        if (gok > getal){
            antwoordLbl.setText("Lager!");
            aantalGok++;
        }           
    }
    if (gok == getal){
        antwoordLbl.setText("Geraden!");
    }
    else if (aantalGok == 8){
        antwoordLbl.setText("Jammer, het getal was "+getal);
    }
}
```

I figured that I'm doing something wrong when trying to read the randomly generated number but I can't figure out how to do it correct. Any tips?

Comment: `int getal = rand.nextInt(100)+1;` creates a **local** method variable which is lost when the method returns.  Move `getal` to be a class variable so it will still be available during a guess.  Also, consider using a better variable name such as `actual`to avoid confusion with `getal` during a guess.

Comment: @AndrewS Sorry, I'm not sure I get what you mean with "Move getal to be a class variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments and based on your code, consider the below class where `actual` stores a randomly generated value each time the "start" button is clicked.  As an instance variable (not class variable as mentioned in the comment), the value continues to be available between methods of the same instance of the class.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ... {
    // keep track of a randomly generated value
    private int actual;  // part of the class, not within a method
                         // each instance of the class will have its own value
                        // the variable exists as long as the instance exists

    private void startBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Random rand = new Random();   // this could also be an instance variable instead of creating a  new one each time
        // int getal = rand.nextInt(100)+1;  getal would be a local method variable and is lost when the method returns
        actual = rand.nextInt(100)+1; // keep track of the random value
   }                                        

    private void guessBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        ...
        int guess = ...  // whatever the user guessed
        if (guess == actual) {
           ...
        } else if (guess > actual) {
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }

}
```

Further reading: search on "java variable scope".

Comment: Are the errors related to this question?  Might need to create a new question.